# Quais os tipos de armazenamento para aplicações desktop?

Tags: java, armazenamento

Bom, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Java para gerenciar meu extrato bancário, para separar os lançamentos por categorias e data, para futuramente gerar gráficos.

Quais são os meios salvar, modificar e consultar os dados? De forma que eu possa facilmente repassar o aplicativo, sem ter a necessidade de instalar um banco de dados a parte, MySQL por exemplo.

Eu já conheço 4 formas, mas não sei se são praticas a longo prazo:

1. Manipular um Json.
2. Manipular um Xml.
3. Criar um banco de dados com SQL Lite e afins.
4. Salvar o objeto serializado no Java.

Perguntas:

- Quais as vantagens e desvantagens dessas formas?
- Qual a mais viável para esse projeto ser fácil de distribuir?
- Existe alguma solução melhor que eu poderia adotar?

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao StackOverFlow Português. Sua pergunta e baseada em opiniões e ela pode ser fechada. Adote a tecnologia que melhor se adapta a sua necessidade, se vc tiver duvidas (Programação) no decorrer do uso dela, vc pode postar a pergunta aqui que a comunidade lhe vai ajudar.  Lembre-se também de postar seu código.

Comment: O banco de dados da sua aplicação vai ter muitas tabelas?

Comment: Eu acho que a edição tornou a pergunta ampla.

Comment: é amplo demais..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Quais as vantagens e desvantagens dessas formas?

Métodos **1** e **2** são bons para dados somente leitura, pois é fácil carregar e acessar o que se deseja.

Entretanto, considerando que você vai frequentemente querer consultar e filtrar os dados em diferentes formas, acredito que seja mais coerente usar um banco de dados embutido no programa como proposta em **3**. Boas alternativas são:

- [H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/)
- [HyperSQL](http://hsqldb.org/)

O item **4** eu nem consideraria como uma forma de armazenamento decente. Isso pode gerar vários problemas se você precisar evoluir sua estrutura de dados.

Outro problema com **1**, **2** e **4** é que você terá que manipular tudo em memória e, para evitar perda der dados, fazer flush constante para o disco. Terá também que se preocupar com a integridade dos arquivos, etc.

Por outro lado, se o programa pretende ser simples e não há muita preocupação com consistência dos dados, nem com consultas mais complexas, gerenciar tudo em memória e serializar para o disco em JSON não é uma má ideia.

> Qual a mais viável para esse projeto ser fácil de distribuir?

A melhor distribuição hoje em dia seria numa aplicação web. Se precisar fazer uso offline, pode criar um APP que funciona com autonomia, mas é capaz de sincronizar com um servidor remoto usando, por exemplo, uma API REST.

Dá mais trabalho, mas com certeza é melhor do que armazenar um banco de dados ou arquivo localmente, principalmente se a ideia é que os dados sejam acessíveis e modificados de vários locais.

Mover arquivos para lá e para cá pode ser uma dor de cabeça. Um dia você sai de casa e esquece de levar a cópia mais recente do arquivo. Aí você fica impedido de fazer qualquer alteração enquanto não voltar para casa. Outro dia você faz uma alteração e não lembra se o arquivo atual é mesmo o mais recente. Se você esquecer em qual ambiente alterou o arquivo pela última vez, ou fizer alterações em dois ambiente sem querer, como vai garantir que os dados atuais estão consistentes?

Entretanto, se você prefere ainda uma versão puramente desktop, o método mais flexível seria usar o banco a partir de um arquivo no disco. Isso é perfeitamente possível e fácil usando os bancos de dados que citei acima.

Existe alguma solução melhor que eu poderia adotar?

Aplicação web, se possível com um aplicativo mobile para lançamentos simples offline e posterior sincronização.

## Considerações

Embora eu tenha procurado me ater bem ao contexto da pergunta, alguns pontos aqui são um tanto opinativos e dependem das necessidades específicas de quem vai usar o programa, além das restrições específicas.

Por exemplo, quem vai usar o programa tem um smartphone? Fica frequentemente sem acesso à internet? Anda sempre com um laptop pessoal?

Comment: A primeira instância, o programa vai ficar sem internet. E apenas em laptop ou computador pessoal.